# VBA Run Time Error 1004 Range of Object_Global Failed

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am unsure what is wrong with my code.  I thought that I set the range correctly but maybe not.  I did try to set multiple ranges.  The error is on the last main row of code "Range("CL_Paid").Paste"

```
 Sub test()

 Dim HR_Paid, HR_Unpaid, E_Paid, E_Unpaid, SE_Paid, SE_Unpaid, CL_Paid, CL_Unpaid As Range
 Set HR_Paid = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:L49")
 Set HR_Unpaid = Sheets("Data").Range("A50:L99")
 Set E_Paid = Sheets("Data").Range("A100:L149")
 Set E_Unpaid = Sheets("Data").Range("A150:L199")
 Set SE_Paid = Sheets("Data").Range("A200:L249")
 Set SE_Unpaid = Sheets("Data").Range("A250:L299")
 Set CL_Paid = Sheets("Data").Range("A300:L349")
 Set CL_Unpaid = Sheets("Data").Range("A350:L399")




   With Sheets("Data")
      .Select
     ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
     ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
     .DisplayPageBreaks = False
     Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
     Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
     For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
          With .Cells(Lrow, "D")

              If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                  If .Value = ("CL") Then .EntireRow.Cut
                      Range("CL_Paid").Paste


             End If

        End With

    Next Lrow
  End With


 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you intentionally use the one-line version of the `If...Then` statement?

The indentation of the line below the `If` looks as though you think it relates to the `If` in some way. You have this:

```
If .Value = ("CL") Then .EntireRow.Cut
    Range("CL_Paid").Paste
```

which has the same effect as this:

```
If .Value = ("CL") Then
    .EntireRow.Cut
End If

Range("CL_Paid").Paste
```

when I suspect that you really want this:

```
If .Value = ("CL") Then
    .EntireRow.Cut
    CL_Paid.Paste
End If
```

You are therefore trying to `Paste` regardless of whether or not the `Cut` ever happened.

Details on the different versions of the `If...Then` statement are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

CLPaid is already a `Range` so use `Cl_Paid.Paste`. However, Paste applies to a `Worksheet`, not a `Range`, so you might consider `PasteSpecial`. Alternatively,

```
.EntireRow.Cut CL_Paid
```

will Cut and Paste (to a Destination) in one step, without using the clipboard.

Note also that

```
Dim HR_Paid, HR_Unpaid, E_Paid, etc As Range
```

does not (in VBA) define all these are Range references. They are all **Variant**'s except for the last one. You would have to use:

```
Dim HR_Paid As Range, HR_Unpaid As Range, E_Paid As Range, etc
```